# How expensive is construction of DOMXPath?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, domdocument

When writing a parser of a complex XML document, I wonder if it is OK to construct `DOMXPath` instances when needed:

```
function parseData($d) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
    // ...
}

function parseMoreData($d) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
    // ...
}

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadXML($xml);
parseData($d);
parseMoreData($d);
```

The alternative would be to create one `DOMXPath` instance in the beginning, then reuse it everywhere in the parser:

```
function parseData($d, $xpath) {
    // ...
}

function parseMoreData($d, $xpath) {
    // ...
}

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($d);
parseData($d, $xpath);
parseMoreData($d, $xpath);
```

Comment: Expensive in which "currency"? Memory? Execution time? Lines of Code? Maintenance? - Into which concrete problem did you run? Did you even run into any that is related to any kind of expensiveness? - Just asking :) As you can see, it's not easy to say what you asked for, I tried to answer it anyway. Please take a look.

Comment: From the top of my head: I was writing an interface to an API that returns results sized in the order of tens of MBs (when less than an MB would be enough, there is lots of redundancy in the XML, incl. debug data). We encountered slowness. In general, I was wondering whether `new DOMXPath($d)` does any parsing, i.e. whether execution time depends on document size, or if execution time is `O(1)`.

Comment: Well, the performing of the actual `DOMXPath::query` takes it's time, however, if you imagine you would need to traverse that XML Tree your own, it's pretty fast (depends a on the xpath query *and* the document size). On the hand the instantiation of a new `DOMXPath` is pretty cheap in PHP, that's also how I started to answer, that it's okay to create many of those - however as I then conclude, for your code-example given, you shouldn't because the parsing methods should use dependency injection instead of creating the xpath their own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very okay to create the `DOMXpath` instances when you need them, there is not much overhead with these built-in classes in PHP. Especially with DOMDocument / DOMXpath, those merely wrap around features of libxml.

So what more plays a role how many (different) documents you've opened, not how many `DOMXpath` objects you have created.

Also instead of passing a `DOMDocument` into the parse function(s):

```
function parseData(DOMDocument $doc) 
{
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    // ...
}
```

You can pass the xpath - it carries the document as well:

```
function parseData(DOMXpath $xpath) 
{
    $doc = $xpath->document;

    // ...
}
```

So your alternative example with two function parameters is technically not necessary at all. As you merely concerned about that detail, this last suggestion should solve your "issue".

And keep in mind that you normally only need to care about performance when you run into a real problem. Here the code merely improves by injecting the object to operate on instead of creating it inside the function. That's called dependency injection and a much better way to write code: Functions should ask (read: have a parameter) for what they need and not create it their own. They should concentrate on the job (here parsing the data) instead of taking care to instantiate a `DOMXPath` first.

---

#### The question of `O(1)` (Big O notation).

How expensive is `new DOMXpath($doc)`? Is it `O(1)`? In comments I answered this with a yes based on what I know from experience and understanding.

Now I also took a look into lxr. When a new `DOMXPath` is created ([constructor in PHP-C-Code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_2/ext/dom/xpath.c#72)), it's merely a wrapper around a structure in libxml (the underlying C-Library of the `DOMDocument` extension): [`xmlXPathContext`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xpath.html#xmlXPathContext).

All this code looks pretty straight forward and only reading/setting single values (not misc size lists or so), so that I'd say now that yes, definitely creating a `DOMXPath` is `O(1)`.

Comment: Could you add to your answer what is the execution time of `new DOMXPath($d)` depending on document size? `O(1)`?

Comment: If `O(1)` means that it takes the same amount of time regardless the document has zero nodes or one hundred thousand nodes then it must be `O(1)`. Take care that this is for `new DOMXPath($doc)` only, not for running the xpath query (!).

Comment: Yes, I mean run time depending on amount of input data. Could you add your comment to your answer?

Comment: @feklee: Edited the answer and also provide some more reference to the underlying sourcecode that should back-it up a bit more as I was talking about experience. It shows you as well how you could research on the details on your own.

Comment: I forgot to link this one, too, it's the concstructor in libxml2 - I only linked the struct in the answer: https://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/tree/xpath.c#n6097 - As you can see, this is all pretty much straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the research concerning runtime! That's what I wanted to know. I don't agree on your advice that passing `$xpath` is better than passing `$d` (document). Each can be derived from the other at `O(1)`. I would have to look at the code, but I believe that there were reasons why I preferred passing `$d`: I probably wanted to build different `$xpath` using the parameters of the `DOMXPath` constructor.

Comment: I don't suggest that because of `O(1)`, I suggest that because of dependency injection and what the role/dedication of the function is. So despite the performance being a non-issue here (it makes no (notable) difference as you correctly state), I would inject the XPath so that the (different) parser can concentrate on parsing, not on `DOMXPath` creation. [Don't look for things](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0)

Comment: Passing the document to a parse function makes sense from the user's (of that function) perspective. He does not even need to know that there is such a thing as an XPath.

Comment: that is a perfectly right poínt, yes. So probably what you might want to do is to create a parser object in which the document gets injected and only the parse methods need to be called (without even passing the document). How does that sound?

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative is of course more efficient because it does not rebuild one domXpath.
But what you have to keep in mind is that the only object you need here is DomXPath. 
As you can see, the constructor of DOMXpath only depends on the DOMDocument instance you give him. So if your functions take only DOMXpath as parameter it would be the same.

You can access to the xpath's document by using `$xpath->document`.

Then, it is like you want, the performance you win is not so significant, only 252 bytes.

About the time you will take, it will become significant only if you use big files as the parse time will be more significant than any other treatment and everytime you start a DOMXPath.
A solution can be to use a factory pattern :

```
class XPathFactory{
    private static instances=array();
    public static function getXPath($doc,$namespacePrefix){
        if(!isset(self::$instances[spl_object_hash($doc).$namespacePrefix]){
           self::$instances[spl_object_hash($doc).$namespacePrefix] = new DOMXPath($doc);
           self::$instances[spl_object_hash($doc).$namespacePrefix]->registerNamespace($namespacePrefix);
         }
         return self::$instances[spl_object_hash($doc).$namespacePrefix];
    }
 }
```

then in your functions you just have to call :

```
 XPathFactory::getXPath($doc,$namespace);
```

and you will get the good XPAth without instanciating too much.

Comment: Thanks! Still, having several `DOMXPath` instances may be preferable, since I could register namespaces differently. Does `DOMXPath` parse the document in any way?

Comment: you can register namespaces independantly. DOMXPath allways parse the doc.

Comment: Well, but I may want to use the same name space prefix for different namespace URIs (just as in the document at hand).

Comment: As it is an object and so a reference each time you change the namespace you change it for the whole object. So it is ok. I don't know what matters here.

Comment: While it is OK to assign a new URI to an existing name space prefix, it does not add to readability.

Comment: of course. Your question was about performance. As I said, in memory, everything is "ok", as 250 bytes is nothing. If you have little (inferior to 4K) files, it should be OK to have multiple DOMXpath. But if you want to use big files, look at the edit I will provide in 2 secs, you can have a good performance improvement.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Could you explicitly state whether or not the `DOMXPath` constructor parses the XML? 2. How do you know that an XPath instance takes up exactly 252 bytes?

Comment: The factory pattern is useless in my case, since I register multiple namespaces with a single `DOMXPath`.